# AttributeError in QGIS model during batchmode processing

Tags: qgis, batch, attributeerror

I'm running a custom model from in batch mode. It has the following tools:

- Raster Calculator
- Polygonize (raster to vector) (GDAL)
- Simplify
- A lot of field calculators
- Drop field(s) (the final tool in the model)

During batch model processing, the name of the model output (a vector layer) is calculated by the following expression:

```
'/MyProject/' || 'ResearchArea' || '/'  ||  
regexp_substr(file_path(@my_raster_input), 'mu_0.\\\\d+') || 
regexp_substr(file_path(@my_raster_input), 'turb_\\\\d+') || 
'.geojson'
```

When I run my model in the normal way, I get no errors, but when running batch processing, the following appears in my log file for every item in the run:

```
The following layers were not correctly generated.
• /MyProject/ResearchArea/mu_0.125_turb_500.geojson
You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

The log messages panel says the following:

```
 CRITICAL    Error loading result layer:
             Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/QGIS33~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\Postprocessing.py", line 229, in handleAlgorithmResults
              results_group = get_layer_tree_results_group(details, context)
              File "/QGIS33~1.2/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\Postprocessing.py", line 154, in get_layer_tree_results_group
              results_group = details.project.layerTreeRoot()
             AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'layerTreeRoot'
```

I know that a `layerTree`  [has to do with the legend widget in QGIS](https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2014/07/06/qgis-layer-tree-api-part-1/). But I have no clue how this relates to the model I use. Interestingly, when I open the resulting `.geojson` files, they can be used as normal and don't seem corrupt. Nevertheless, the error does not allow to run the entire batch from start to end.

How can I fix this AttributeError (preferably within the model designer)?
I'm using version 3.32 Lima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue may very well be a bug in the software. I noticed that the error does not appear when you tick the option `load layers upon completion`. The drawback is that you do get all the generated layers in your project, but on the other hand, it is a minor nuisance compared to not being able to use batch-mode at all.
[image]